# How to plot correct dates with matplotlib?

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, pandas

I'm trying to play with Python, pandas, and matplotlib, but am having some noob issues.

My simple script:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import Quandl
start_date = datetime.datetime.now() - relativedelta(days=5)
data_frame = Quandl.get("GOOG/NASDAQ_AAPL",
  trim_start=start_date)

import matplotlib  
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(data_frame['Close'].index, data_frame['Close'])
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.savefig('plot')
plt.close()
```

plots this figure:
[image]

How can I get the x-axis to print out nicely formatted dates (maybe 2014-04-24)?

I'm guessing it has to do with `data_frame['Close'].index`.  It prints out as:

```
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2014-04-21, ..., 2014-04-25]
Length: 5, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

I was expecting something along the lines of `[1950-01-31 00:00:00, ..., 2013-02-28 00:00:00]` from the online articles I've been reading.  So I'm debating if I need to use something like `datetime.strptime` but am not sure if that's right or not; and am not sure how I would be able to use it concisely with the datetime index.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Pandas objects have special formatting for DatetimeIndexes. Did you try `data_frame['Close'].plot()`?

Comment: @TomAugspurger Thanks for the hint.  I've tried it and it came back with `raise ValueError("x and y must have same first dimension")   
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension`.

Comment: @TomAugspurger When I print out `data_frame['Close'].plot()`, I get `Axes(0.125,0.1;0.775x0.8)`.  It seems like there's another step I need to take, but am not sure what to search for.  Thanks again for your help.  Sorry this was two comments...I was trying to add line breaks and it sent. :)

Comment: @TomAugspurger Sorry, you were right.  `data_frame['Close'].plot()` worked.  I didn't know enough to understand what you meant.  Thanks!  If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.  :)

Answer (score 0):

In `matplotlib`, you can get the desired x tick format by directly modifying the `major_formater`:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
plt.plot(data_frame['Close'].index, data_frame['Close'])
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y/%b/%d-%H:%S'))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=1))
plt.xticks(rotation=45, fontsize = 8)
```

[image]